# Run program with administrator permissions from user account

Tags: windows, permissions, administrator

I need to set up a lap-top for a colleague. He should have normal user account, but in order to connect to the university network, he requires a program that needs administrative permissions to run. The program is a command line utility.

Is it possible to somehow run the program as administrator from his account, without requiring him to enter administrator password?

P.S. We tried running program as a service, but that didn't work out because the program requires interaction with the user (credentials for university network).

Comment: What OS version does he use?

Comment: Windows 7 operating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use runas command:

```
runas /savecred /user:Administrator command
```

But as well-pointed by Tejs, this is will open computer to security attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Umm.. no? That's the whole point of the security context requiring him to enter the administrative password.

If you could, there would be a whole host of nasty viruses out in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RunAsUser](http://dirtycoding.blogspot.pt/2013/02/always-run-program-as-administrator.html), works in my Windows XP, I'm not sure it works in other windows system.