# Run a spefic program as administrator from an unprivileged user account without asking for password

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, scheduled-tasks, uac

My son does not have admin access on his computer but wants to run a [game](https://client.badlion.net/) that asks for admin privileges.

I am looking for a way to run just this one program as administrator without prompting for password.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/427175/83314) suggests using `runas /user:Administrator /savecred`, but that will save the Administrator password in the credentials store and allow to run *any* program with admin rights, which is something I don't want to happen.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/611010/83314) suggests creating a manually-triggered task in the task scheduler (also outlined [here](https://www.badlion.net/forum/thread/220796/post/1207354#1207354)), which would be a good solution if I could get it to work.

I suspect that the suggestion assumes that the user is logged in as an administrator and just wants to avoid the UAC prompt, which is not the case here.

Here's what I found so far:

- I can only create a task that runs under an admin account if I run the task manager as an admin.  Otherwise it will not let me do that.
- When the task is created in task manager that was run as an admin, it is not visible in task manager started as a non-admin.
- Trying to start the task from task manager (as admin) does start the process, but does not display any UI.
- Trying to run the task from a shortcut does not even start the process.

Please advise.

**Edit:**

"This question already has an answer here:
Run Badlion Client in a non-admin account (1 answer)"

It absolutely doesn't!

That answer states "t the time you can only Open the Badlion Client WITH Admin perms".

Which is exactly what I am trying (and failing) to do from a non-privileged account.

Comment: What you want is, in general, simply not possible. Contact the game support people and ask (1) is there a way to run the game from Task Scheduler; and (2) do they have a manifest file that allows the game to be run by a non-admin person.

Comment: You can edit the manifest in the exe which determines if it has to *Run As Admin*. Download ResHacker (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) which more than likely will need to be *Run As Admin*. Open the exe, select the *Manifest*. Change `RequireAdministrator` to `AsInvoker`. Then *Action* menu, *Modify*, *File* menu, *Save*. You can use ProcessMonitor to watch what it is accessing (error 5 Access Denied) and change security on just that object. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon. It is likely the anti cheat features want to be admin.

Comment: PS. Any elevated program with a File Open / Save As dialog can start any program (right click a file in Notepad's File Open dialog). Programs started by an elevated program are elevated. Therefore a user can make themselves an Administrator.

Comment: Would running this game in a VM be an option?

Comment: The reason this question was closed, is that at this time, Badlion can only be opened with an Administrator account.  If your account does not have those permissions then it cannot be launch Badlion.